# Running Derby as a server on Linux using JDK11

Tags: linux, derby, openjdk-11

## I am at my wits end!

- I have a minimal install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 and OpenJDK 11 (headless).
- Downloaded, to a local folder are the java 9+ binaries for Derby (db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin)

*Path and Environment settings are all correct!*

When I start the server `startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0`, I get an error when doing a simple connect using the `ij` command line tool

```
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbname;create=true';
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'dbname', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
```

The derby.log file makes reference to:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH")
```

Looking further into this error, I learned that I somehow need a security.profile.  I found this website that seemed to be the answers to my problems. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/04/apache-derby-database-jvm-security-policy.html

Following these pretty straight-forward instructions, I get:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
org.apache.derby.shared.common.security.SystemPermission( "engine", "usederbyinternals" )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your precise question is, but since you seem to be struggling with how to configure the Java security manager for your Derby Network Server, try starting here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/security/csecjavasecurity.html

Comment: If I put the following as my server.policy it works.
grant {
     permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";
};

Answer (score 2):

For the next person who has this strange problem (it seems to happen with some regularity, here's a simple workaround, copied from [this FAQ page at Chalmers Institute of Technology](https://chalmers.instructure.com/courses/8915/pages/f-dot-a-q-common-issues):

> Q: When we try to create a database in Derby and the database explorer in NetBeans, we get one or more of the following error(s):
>
> An error occurred while creating the database:
> java.sql.NonTransientConnectionException: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE:
> 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: ...
>
> Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
> ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH")
>
> A: This is some kind of missconfiguration in the JVM with a very aggressive security policy that doesn't allow applications to fetch the time on the system (since epoch). The solution is to edit `~/.java.policy` or `[java.home]/lib/security/java.policy` and add the following:
>
> grant {
> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH", "read";
> };
>
> If you are on Windows you can read about where this policy file is supposed to be located here;
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 1):

Apache-Derby is a database management system prepared for a multi-user environment, therefore, when you execute the startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0 instruction, you are telling it by default to take certain security into account, and that is why it does not let you do an insecure connection such as ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://172.16.17.31:1527/BBDD_server;create=true';

because you are connecting without specifying username and password, so you should either connect by specifying username + password, or start the server without any security:

startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0 -noSecurityManager

More help:
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/adminguide/tadminnetservopen.html

https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/adminguide/tadminnetservbasic.html