# DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples'

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, derby

I'm following the first cup tutorial, but I'm stuck at the end of [chapter 4](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-firstcup/web-application006.html) with this exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001

In the Projects tab I select the `firstcup-war` project, right-click and select Run.

The output tab says:

```
Deploying on GlassFish Server
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
In-place deployment at /home/t/NetBeansProjects/firstcup-war/target/firstcup-war
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
```

The tab *Java DB Database Process* says

```
Fri May 08 21:09:39 CEST 2020 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri May 08 21:09:39 CEST 2020 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.14.2.0 - (1828579) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

The tab *GlassFish Server* has a long trail of exceptions:

```
...
Info:   EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5
Warning:   RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
Warning:   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
Warning:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001]
Severe:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:228)
    [...]

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [firstcup-war]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:324)
    at 
    ...

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [firstcup-war] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'sun-appserv-samples', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM01::SQLSTATE: XJ001
Error Code: 0
```

I'm not sure what parts are relevant, for what it's worth here is the full log: 
https://pastebin.com/cRE9mVMQ

Comment: Try practicing with the simpler Derby tutorial first: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/getstart/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure because I don't see your derby logs, but it is possible that it is connected to a Java permissions error.

If this appears in derby.log:

```
Java exception: 'access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH"")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683141/18924722).

I resolved the problem by adding

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH";
```

to `/etc/java-11-openjdk/security/java.policy` (Ubuntu) in the grant section.